# How are __addgs* used, and what is GS?

Tags: visual-c++, x86-64, intrinsics, thread-local-storage, memory-segmentation

On Microsoft's site can be found [some details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/addgsbyte-addgsword-addgsdword-addgsqword?view=msvc-160) of the

```
__addgsbyte  ( offset, data )
__addgsword  ( offset, data )
__addgsdword ( offset, data )
__addgsqword ( offset, data )
```

intrinsic functions. It is stated that `offset` is

> *the offset from the beginning of GS*. I presume that *GS* refers to the processor register.

How does *GS* relate to the stack, if at all? Alternatively, how can I calculate an offset with respect to *GS*?

(And, are there any 'gotchas' relating to this and particular calling conventions, such as `__fastcall`?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GS register does not relate to the stack at all and therefore no relation to callign convensions.  On x64 versions of Windows it is used to point to operating system data:

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64#Windows):

> Instead of FS segment descriptor on x86 versions of the Windows NT
>   family, GS segment descriptor is used to point to two operating system
>   defined structures: Thread Information Block (NT_TIB) in user mode and
>   Processor Control Region (KPCR) in kernel mode. Thus, for example, in
>   user mode GS:0 is the address of the first member of the Thread
>   Information Block. Maintaining this convention made the x86-64 port
>   easier, but required AMD to retain the function of the FS and GS
>   segments in long mode — even though segmented addressing per se is not
>   really used by any modern operating system.

Note that those intrinsics are only available in kernel mode (e.g. device drivers).  To calculate an offset, you would need to know what segment of memory GS is pointing to.  So in kernel mode you would need to know the layout of the Processor Control Region.

Personally I don't know what the use of these would be.

Comment: Thanks (to all) for the information. It is useful to have an answer even in the negative. Now I will concentrate on other approaches to solving my problem (e.g. extenal assembly, higher-level intrinsics, asm to intrinsic 'direct' translation, ...).

Comment: I realize this is a late comment, but it appears that [the statement about intrinsics being only available to kernel mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htss0hyy(v=vs.80).aspx) is _false_.  I just created a user-mode application using `__readgsdword`, and it compiled for x64 with both Visual Studio 2010 and the Windows Server 2008 DDK.

Answer (score 1):

these intrinsics, along with there fs counterparts have no real use except for accessing OS specific data, as such its most likely that these where added purely to make the windows developers lives easier (I've personally used this for inline TLS access)

Answer (score 1):

The [doc you linked](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/addgsbyte-addgsword-addgsdword-addgsqword?view=msvc-160) says:

> Add a value to a memory location specified by an offset relative to the beginning of the GS segment.

That means it's an intrinsic for this asm instruction: `add gs:[offset], data` (a normal memory-destination `add` with a GS segment override) with your choice of operand-size.

The compiler can presumably pick any addressing mode for the `offset` part, and `data` can be a register or immediate, thus either or both of offset and data can be runtime variables or constants.

The actual linear (virtual) address accessed will be `gs_base + offset`, where gs_base is set via an MSR to any address (by the OS on its own, or by you making a system call).

In user-space at least, Windows normally uses GS for TLS (thread local storage).  The answer claiming this intrinsic only works in kernel code is mistaken.  It doesn't add *to* the GS base, it adds to memory at an address relative to the existing GS base.

MS only seems to document this intrinsic for x64, but it's a valid instruction in 32-bit mode as well.  IDK why they'd bother to restrict it.  (Except of course the qword form: 64-bit operand size isn't available in 32-bit mode.)

---

Perhaps the compiler doesn't know how to generally optimize `__readgsdword` / (operation on that data) / `__writegsdword` into a memory-destination instruction with the same gs:offset address.  If so, this intrinsic would just be a code-size optimization.

But perhaps it's sometimes relevant to force the compiler to do it as a single instruction to make it atomic wrt. interrupts on this core (but *not* wrt. accesses by other CPU cores).  IDK if that's an intended use case is; this answer is just explaining what that one line of documentation means in terms of x86 asm and memory-segmentation.